# How to make a controller independent in App Delegate?

Tags: swift

So in the `AppDelegate.swift` file I have a UINavigationController as the root view controller and a mainController as the topViewController for the navigationController. I have all the data instantiated here so it can be independent. Now, I wanted to make MenuController as my topViewController but I'm not sure how to call the mainController from here.

To be more specific, I am creating a crossword game and I've been focusing on the logic and implementation of the grid and such. Now I wanted to make a Menu as my first screen before displaying the crossword game.

MainMenu -> MenuController 
CrosswordGame -> MainController

Here is the code I have without the MainMenu implementation in the `AppDelegate.swift`

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Create a ButtonStore
        let buttonStore = ButtonStore()
        let levelStore = LevelStore()

        // Access the MainController and set its buttonStore
        let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let mainController = navController.topViewController as! MainController
        mainController.buttonStore = buttonStore
        mainController.levelStore = levelStore
        return true
    }
```

And here is what I have now

```
        // Create a ButtonStore
        let buttonStore = ButtonStore()
        let levelStore = LevelStore()

        // Access the MainController and set its buttonStore
        let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let menuController = navController.topViewController as! MenuController
        // Instantiate MainController and add buttonStore / levelStore to MainController


        return true
```

I just don't want my Crossword Game to lose its data when pressing the back key back to the MainMenu. Another question is, is it viable to put it in the AppDelegate or instantiate the MainController in the MenuController.

Comment: You can set both view controllers at once using the `setViewControllers` method on `UINavigationController`. If the game is on the bottom of the stack, and you push the menu on top, when the menu is popped the game would remain. Every time you want to bring up the menu you would need to push it on top of the game.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific when using `setViewControllers`. I've tried making the view controller beforehand to but it in the list.

Comment: I added an answer to clarify since its hard to format code in the comments. Not sure if you are using Storyboard or code for creating you vc's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //create your view controllers and set any properties
    let game =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainControllerIdentifier")
    let menu =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuControllerIdentifier")

    //create the navigation controller
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()

    //set the content controllers on the nav controller
    navController.setViewControllers([game, menu], animated: false)

   //assign the navigation controller as the root controller of the window
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Comment: I ended up trying to use this but I wasn't able to get it to work because the `game MainController()` requires a `NSCode` as an argument. Do you know what to put in as the NSCode?

Comment: How are you creating your view controllers, are you using Storyboards? If so you need to load your `game` controller from the storyboard.  `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameControllerIdentifier")`

Comment: woah thank you so much for helping me. I have definitely learned a lot. I still to learn how to save the data when switching controllers but I'll do research on it since that is a whole different question.